# Sphinx - how to generate dynamic level of headings (change level, offset)

Tags: python-sphinx, asciidoctor

I am trying out sphinx + readthedocs as my documentation generator. I would like to have multiple subfiles included in my index file. There are files (sections) that I would like to use in two different index, but as they (index files) can have different hierarchies I will have problems with levels of sections.

Is there any way to achieve with Sphinx effect similiar to asciidoctor "offset" like mentioned here : http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2016/09/awesome-asciidoctor-change-level-offset.html ?

Comment: Sphinx does not have a "leveloffset" feature for included files. But there is a `toctree` directive: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#table-of-contents.

Comment: Thank, but i do not see how this helps me with my problem.
Lets say, that I have chapter_n.rst file which starts with 2nd level heading and has several subheadings. Next I would like to use this chapter_n.rst in different documentation, where it should start with 3rd level heading (and subheadings should be also offset by +1 level). Is it doable with sphinx ?